# Blender 2.8 rendering is using a lot of psu power

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

So when I'm rendering something in blender my pc makes a lot of noise, but like airplane level noises. So I checked my task manager, and it uses about 60% cpu power, 80% gpu power, but psu usage is also marked as very high. Is this normal? Is there anything to make this less extreme without doing further rendering optimisation?

I'm rendering in Eevee btw.

Comment: That is normal, GPUs require quite a bit of power. Just make sure that the PSU you're using is suitable to supply enough power for your entire build under full load.

Comment: Also make sure it doesn't overheat and get proper ventilation.